# how remove horizontal scroll bar for iframe on google chrome

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to have vertical scrolling enable and horizontal scrolling off.

using **scrolling="no"** is not what i want since i still want the vertical scrolling.

I've tried adding this to css

```
  #myiframe{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
  }
```

but it still shows the horizontal-scroll bar for chrome only. the rest of the browsers are fine.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have access to iframe source or at least are the pages from the same domain?

Comment: I do. but using overflow-x:hidden does not work for chrome only. it works for all other browsers.

Comment: Actually if you put style `body {overflow-x:hidden;}` (or even `html {overflow-x:hidden;}`) into the page that is showing *inside of iframe* - it works in Chrome too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have access to iframe source page you can place

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

inside of that page. If you don't, but at least pages are from the same domain, I believe something like this from the parent page should work:

```
#myiframe body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

If none of the above is true - you can simulate "overflow-x: hidden" by actually hiding the horizontal scrollbar inside of the iframe container. Place Iframe into a container DIV of a lesser height, e.g.:

```
<div id="myiframecontainer">
    <iframe id="myiframe" src="http://en.wikipedia.org"  />
</div>

#myiframecontainer {
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

#myiframe {
    width:100%;
    height:420px; 
}
```

Since iframe height is bigger than div's height and div's overflow is set to hidden - horizontal scrollbar of the iframe will be hidden. Vertical still remains operational.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5DPgf/

Comment: thank you! this seems to be a google chrome issue that has not been fixed. but your solution about placing it to a div with a lesser height is a temporary fix.

Comment: Option 3 was just what I needed. Well thought!