# Yet another question about iframe and horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, sass

In my React application, I am using an `iframe` which the content is provided by the server. not adding anything about `overflow` to the style, I see a horizontal scroll bar (*no draggable scroller just the bar*) only in Chrome and not other browsers like FireFox and Edge.

adding the `overflow-x: hidden;` the wrapper `div` of I frame style is like

```
.article-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
  iframe {
    flex: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  iframe.body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

adding `overflow-x: hidden;` nighter from CSS file nor as an inline style to the iframe does not work and still see that scroll bar (in chrome)
I know the content of the iframe is not manipulable from outside, just in case I added the `iframe.body`

so My question is, Why only see it in Chrome, and is there any way to hide the X-axis scroll?
is it something related to Flex and direction?

> My main question is why it only happens in Chrome, and what is the difference in render or browser engine that makes such a difference. wrapping the iframe in a div with a lesser height is not an answer, it is a hack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how remove horizontal scroll bar for iframe on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648203/how-remove-horizontal-scroll-bar-for-iframe-on-google-chrome)

Comment: Did you try all the solutions mentioned in the approved answer of the other post ? Even the "If none of the above is true - you can simulate "overflow-x: hidden"" part or are you just bothering us without reading the full answer ?

Comment: Yes, I have read that and also many other posts, those were not working that I have posted here. I am not searching for a silly hack workaround, so it seems since 2013, (the answer you have mentioned) nothing in Chrome is changed

Comment: Look, your tone here does not encourage us to help you. I understand that you want a 2019 solution. Then maybe don't use iframes in 2019. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can add scrolling = "no" in the iframe tag

```
<iframe src="your path" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```